# Comment restrictions Wodpress

Tags: plugins, users, comments

I want to restrict new registered users on my WordPress site from writing comments until 3 days passed their registration date.
What solution do you recommend?
thanks in advanced.

Comment: Is your site hosted on wordpress.com? If so: did you ask their support?

Comment: no my cms is wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

The [comments_open()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_open/) boolean function return is filtered by 'comments_open'. Untested, pseudo code as a guide:

```
add_filter( 'comments_open', function( $open ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $open = $open && $user && time() - mysql2date( 'U', $user->user_registered ) > 3 * DAY_IN_SECONDS;
    return $open;
} );
```

No guest users will be able to comment either, and I guess that is also what you want.